# Why would user IDs differ when a chat is re-exported from Telegram?

Tags: telegram

On October 24th 2020 I exported my Telegram chats to a **result.json** file. Doing it again today (January 4th 2021) I see all the message *from_id*s have changed. Here is what one message looked like in the earlier file:

```
{
  "id": 35454,
  "type": "message",
  "date": "2020-10-09T09:42:38",
  "from": "Milton Widdle",
  "from_id": 77928200,
  "text": [
   "Mum and I got notices from Elections Canada
```

Here is how the same message now appears in the latest file:

```
     {
      "id": 35454,
      "type": "message",
      "date": "2020-10-09T09:42:38",
      "from": "Milton Widdle",
      "from_id": 4372895496,
      "text": [
       "Mum and I got notices from Elections Canada
```

All the chats in the file are affected. There have been no administrative changes (e.g. groups converted to supergroups) in the interval. Do from_ids just change sometimes or have I/we done something to cause it?

Comment: I believe Telegram regularly cycles user-ids to protect user privacy and hinder bots and companies trying to slurp user data - but I may be wrong.

Comment: Looks like you did something, because I'm using the same `user_id` for many years.

Comment: In a way this is a non-issue. Now that I know *from_id*s are not enduring I have to be able to handle the situation. Once I can handle the change of ID it no longer matters what causes it. They could change every time for all I care. So instead of this being a question it is a warning: IDs can work for years as they did for me and for wowkin2, until they don't. Be prepared.